# I have firebase RealtimeDatabase Based live application and someone changed the data how can he do that?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

This is the rule of Firebase RealtimeDatabase.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually you open the database for everyone to `read` and `write`. So, Anybody can update the data. You should update the rule to restrict it. Check this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security

Answer (score 0):

Your security rules allow anyone with an internet connection to view and modify your database.  If that's not what you want, then you'll have to modify them to suit your app's security needs.  Please [read the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) to learn how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow read and write data to `RealtimeDatabase` for firebase authenticated users only, then you can set `RealtimeDatabase` Rules as follows:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
       "$uid": {
         ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
         ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
       }
    }
  }
}
```

And to Perform Read and Write Operations on Firebase `RelatimeDatabase`, Follow these routes like, `main-->users-->$uid-->Data` to maintain live application user's data. And update data in Android using,

```
mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this rule, it'll allow the user to read/write only if user is logged in.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```